# Is it possiblle to Implement next_permutation() on a STL set<t>

Tags: c++, stl, permutation

Given this set

```
   set<string> s = {"a","b","c"};
```

is it possible to implement next_permutation() to get all combinations, where elements to do not repeat and order matters?

Comment: You don't reorder elements in `std::set`. Is this a well-founded question?

Comment: I am trying to get all combinations of that set. Not send the data back to a set.

Comment: *"`std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key."* from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) pretty much sums it up. Know your containers.

Comment: I am not asking how to rewrite a set as set in a different order.  I am asking "Is it possible to Implement next_permutation() on a STL set<t>" not create rearrange a set as you keep suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible.  [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an associative container and maintains an strict weak ordering.  [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) transforms the range it is given which would break the ordering.

If you need to get the permutations of the contents of the `set` I suggest you use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can copy the set into the vector and then get the permutation from that.

```
std::set<int> set_data;
//fill set
std::vector<int> temp(set_data.begin(), set_data.end());
do
{
    // code goes here
}
while(std::next_permutation(temp.begin(), temp.end()));
```